# Glassfish - Reload XHTML/JSP files that are within the META-INF/resources folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish-3, servlet-3.0

The servlet 3.0 specification allows one to package static resources like js/css/jsp/xhtml files within the META-INF/resources folder of jars that reside within the WEB-INF folder.

If i would like to make a change to those XHTML files while the war is already deployed, how can i do so?

I've already tried creating a copy of the same XHTML file with the same folder structure under the context root but it doesnt seem to work.

I tried looking via jconsole to dynamically reload the xhtml file but couldn't find anything that could help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit more, i realized that you need to first copy over the file with the same folder structure to the context root and then restart the server. Subsequent edits to the xhtml files within the context root will now pick up the changes to them, without requiring a server restart.